# cannot print the model data on console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
    define(function(require) {
        var $ = require('jquery'),
                Backbone = require('backbone'),
                People = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function() {

                var people_object = new People({name: "How Bizarre", artist: "OMC"});
                var people_collections = new PeopleCollection([people_object]);
                console.log(people_collections.models);
            }

        }),
        PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: People,
        });

        return {
            People: People,

        };

    });



  require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'app/models/persons'], function($,Backbone,persons{           
           var p = new persons.People();
   });
```

Here i write above code to display some data on console but when i try that i ve got following error message on the console.I am  new to backbone js.can u tell me where am i wrong

```
<error>
w.pick
a.Model
r
Backbone.Model.extend.initialize
a.Model
r
Backbone.Model.extend.initialize
a.Model
r
Backbone.Model.extend.initialize
a.Model
```

Comment: Why are your creating collection in a model? And you have a few bugs in this code. I will try to explain how to use `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone.Collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your error occurs from circular dependency (infinite loop), cause you have kind of infinite recursion. Any time you initialize people like `new People()`, `initialize` method of that model call the same 'new Person()' and so on....

I guess you are using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

So try like this:

**human.js**

```
define(function(require){
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({
       defaults: {
          name: 'Test', 
          surname: 'Testovyan', 
          sex: 1
       }
    });

    return Human;

});
```

**people.js**

```
define(function(require){
    var Backbone = require('backbone');
    var Human = require('path/to/human');
    var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function () {
           console.log(this);
        },
        model: Human,
        url: '/path/to/remote/url'
    });

    return People;
});
```

**controller_or_view.js**

```
define(function(require){

    require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'path/to/people'], function () {
        var newPeople = [{name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'}, {name: 'Jane', surname: 'Smith'}];   
        var people = new People(newPeople);
        });  

});
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j261fjf7/4/) with the same code.

This is the best way to create your collection of People.
Create model, create collection with model attribute which references your model. Then Initialize your collection with array of objects, which then will automatically became models or initialize your collection without models and fetch them from remote.

Hope this helps.